# How to get all wikipedia accounts made within timeframe?

Tags: web-scraping, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to replicate [this](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2038558.2038561) paper, where they use a random sample of user accounts made between September 9th, 2010 and February 14th, 2011. How can I use the wikipedia API to get this data?

I can't seem to figure out how to use their API's usercontribs to do this (or anything else)

Answer (score 1):

[`list=usercontribs`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Usercontribs) provides, well, user contributions. What you need is [`list=logevents`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Logevents).

The corresponding action is `newusers/create`, for "creation by anonymous user" (*not* `newusers/create2`, which means "creation by registered user").

Since you seem to want only the usernames, `leprop` should be set to `user`. `lestart` and `leend` are where you specify the timestamps; note that the first must be later than the second when `ledir` is `older` (the default) and vice versa.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php
?action=query
&format=json
&formatversion=2

&list=logevents
&leprop=user
&leaction=newusers%2Fcreate
&lestart=2011-02-14T23%3A59%3A59.000Z
&leend=2010-09-09T00%3A00%3A00.000Z
```

Try it [using the API sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&list=logevents&leprop=user&leaction=newusers%2Fcreate&lestart=2011-02-14T23%3A59%3A59.000Z&leend=2010-09-09T00%3A00%3A00.000Z).

Each response will have a `lecontinue` token that you may use in your next request.